# How to Edit a Silverlight treeview data bound to ria services then to Entity Framework and SQL recursive table

Tags: silverlight, treeview, ria, edit

I am searching for guidance on how to edit add, update and delete on a Silverlight treeview connected to a simple hierarchical sql server table using entity framework, ria services and data binding.

Answer (score -1):

I've looked the same info, and have found it here: https://betaforums.silverlight.net/forums/p/177689/416299.aspx